# How can I get the timezone adjusted hour for each row in a pandas DataFrame when working with multiple timezones?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame where the index is a `uuid` and it has two columns: `publication_datetime` and `timezone`. I would like to get the timezone adjusted hour for this column to determine if it was published in the morning, afternoon, or evening.

I have come up with a solution using apply that works for small datasets but either gives me errors (see below) or is just too slow for larger datasets.

Overall, I'm unsure how to handle datetimes in pandas when the datetime isn't an index. The design decision for this was simply because datetime is not the unique identifier, `uuid` is.

```
import pandas as pd

def time_of_day(hour):
    if 0 <= hour < 12:
        return "morning"
    elif 12 <= hour < 16:
        return "afternoon"
    elif 16 <= hour < 24:
        return "evening"

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "uuid": [0,1,2,3,4], 
    "publication_timestamp": [
        "2015-07-28 00:10:05.852", 
        "2015-10-03 00:17:43.000", 
        "2015-08-20 01:15:52.693", 
        "2015-09-09 00:02:03.083", 
        "2015-12-08 00:02:41.390"
    ], 
    "timezone": ["US/Central", "US/Eastern", "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific", "US/Mountain"]
}).set_index('uuid')

df['publication_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.publication_timestamp)

df

#        publication_timestamp     timezone
# uuid
# 0    2015-07-28 00:10:05.852   US/Central
# 1    2015-10-03 00:17:43.000   US/Eastern
# 2    2015-08-20 01:15:52.693   US/Eastern
# 3    2015-09-09 00:02:03.083   US/Pacific
# 4    2015-12-08 00:02:41.390  US/Mountain

ts = pd.Index(df.publication_timestamp).tz_localize('UTC')

ts

# DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-28 00:10:05.852000+00:00',
#                       '2015-10-03 00:17:43+00:00',
#                '2015-08-20 01:15:52.693000+00:00',
#                '2015-09-09 00:02:03.083000+00:00',
#                '2015-12-08 00:02:41.390000+00:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)

ts[0], ts[0].hour

# (Timestamp('2015-07-28 00:10:05.852000+0000', tz='UTC'), 0)

ts[0].tz_convert('US/Central'), ts[0].tz_convert('US/Central').hour

# (Timestamp('2015-07-27 19:10:05.852000-0500', tz='US/Central'), 19)

df['hour'] = ts.hour
df['adjusted_hour'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.publication_timestamp.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert(row.timezone).hour, axis=1)
df['time_of_day'] = df.adjusted_hour.map(time_of_day)

df

#        publication_timestamp     timezone  hour  adjusted_hour time_of_day
# uuid
# 0    2015-07-28 00:10:05.852   US/Central     0             19     evening
# 1    2015-10-03 00:17:43.000   US/Eastern     0             20     evening
# 2    2015-08-20 01:15:52.693   US/Eastern     1             21     evening
# 3    2015-09-09 00:02:03.083   US/Pacific     0             17     evening
# 4    2015-12-08 00:02:41.390  US/Mountain     0             17     evening
```

On the larger dataset, this is the error I receive:

> Exception ignored in: 'pandas.tslib._localize_tso' Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 3547, in
>   pandas.tslib._get_dst_info (pandas/tslib.c:60454)   File
>   "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1138, in pandas.tslib._get_utcoffset
>   (pandas/tslib.c:22226) AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute
>   'utcoffset'

Comment: I opened a Github issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is some bad data in the timezone column that is producing your error; I can reproduce the error with a very small dataframe if I have a numeric value for a time zone:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"uuid": [0,1,2,3,4,5],
"publication_timestamp": [
    "2015-07-28 00:10:05.852",
    "2015-10-03 00:17:43.000",
    "2015-08-20 01:15:52.693",
    "2015-09-09 00:02:03.083",
    "2015-12-08 00:02:41.390",
    "2015-12-08 00:13:32.243",
],
"timezone": ["US/Central", "US/Eastern", "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific", "US/Mountain", 123.4]
}).set_index('uuid')
```

followed by the same operations you show above gives

```
Exception AttributeError: "'float' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'" in 'pandas.tslib._localize_tso' ignored
```

after the 'adjusted_hour' line.

Comment: That was exactly right. I forgot to account for NA's when I created my timezone mapping. Thank you so much!